# Spark AR multiple UI pickers?

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to figure out a way to add multiple UI pickers on Spark AR.

For example, let's say I am making a beautify filter and I would want to let the user change the brow colour, lip colour and blush colours seperately. (but shown at the same time)

I think I might have to use multiple UI pickers for that? a picker for changing the lip colour, a picker for changing the brow colour, a picker for changing the blush colour. BUt I am not sure if that's possible.

What I thought I could also do is to use the UI picker to let the user choose the eyebrow/lip/blush and then use the tap to change function to change the colours? I am not sure if that makes sense.